# How to associate a log file with compilation mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a compilation log file, say `err.log`. How can I use the contents of this file to navigate between compilation errors?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `M-x compilation-mode` or `M-x compilation-minor-mode` to switch the buffer into "compilation" mode, so that Emacs tries to parse error messages and turn them into links to the relevant line in the source file. Then you can go to the next / previous error with `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p`.